# How to install Pod Library by excluding SPECIFIC .h .m FILES or How to remove SPECIFIC .h .m FILES in Pod Library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking

In my iOS App I am using third party libraries with cocoa pods

For some reason In One Third part library, I need that library but some specific files in that library are not required

So that i need to install the pod with out those files

For Ex: I am installing library with by specifying the bellow line in my PodFile

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
```

The AFNetworking is installed successfully in the app.

But here, I need to exclude some files in AFNetworking given bellow

```
UIWebView+AFNetworking.h & .m
UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.h & .m
UIButton+AFNetworking.h & .m
```

Is there ant way to exclude those files while installing the pod library.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to get rid of UIWebView in AFNetworking, due to App Store error?

Comment: Yes, 4.0 can solve the issue but app crashing continuously and having less time to resolve those right now. So that I want to use AFENETWork 3.1.0 without UIWebview files due to avoid crashes in the above versions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can exclude specific files. But you can exclude some subspec. Above files are part AFNetWorking/UIKit

So in your pod file it would look like this.

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.2.1', :subspecs => ['Reachability', 'Serialization', 'Security', 'NSURLSession']
```

Comment: Thank you So much @ibnetariq it works as expected with just a small change
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking-umbrella.h>
instead of #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

Answer (score 1):

you can fork it to your repositories, change the .podspec file, and install it from the forked source.

```
pod ‘ AFNetworking’, :git => ‘https://github.com/[yourName]/AFNetworking.git’
```